# Mac OS - Is it possible to sign in to iCloud via touch id instead of using the password?

Tags: macos, icloud, password, touch-id

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro 15 running Mojave and from time to time I see this annoying iCloud popup saying I'm not logged in and that I have to enter my AppleID password. I have TouchID set up and use it to unlock the Mac and all the other things listed in the system preferences.

Is it possible to use touch id to sign in to iCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not at this time.**

Currently, TouchID allows you to

- unlock your apple devices
- Authorize payments/purchases from ApplePay, iTunes Store, App Store and the iBooks Store
- Unlock/authorize 3rd party app usage (Developer supported)

[About Touch ID advanced security technology](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587)

> You can use it to authorize purchases from the iTunes Store, App Store, and iBooks Store, as well as with Apple Pay. Developers can also allow you to use Touch ID to sign into their apps.

You may see this in a future update, but (IMO) it acts like a second factor in a [2FA authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) when trying to gain access into your iCloud account.